# How to add object property to satisfy class type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

As per code below inside the "**localRegister**" function, I added the '**userId**' and '**accountType**' to the **createUserObj** object using the bracket notation, so it can satisfy the properties of the **User** class type.

But I am still getting that message saying that User is missing the userId, accountType properties.

Seems like a simple issue that I just couldn't figure out...how do we make Typescript understand that those properties has been added already, or is there another proper way to add properties?

Thanks in advance.

**user.service.ts (partial code)**

```
  async localRegister(createUserDto: LocalUserDto) {
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(createUserDto.password, 10);
    let createUserObj = { ...createUserDto, password: passwordHash };

    createUserObj['userId'] = uuid();
    createUserObj['accountType'] = 'local';

    this.userCreate(createUserObj);  // <====== typescript error here
       //   Argument of type '{ password: string; username: string; email: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
       //   Type '{ password: string; username: string; email: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'User': userId, accountType
  }

  async userCreate(userObj: User) {
    const createdUser = new this.userModel(userObj);
    try {
      await createdUser.save();
    } catch (err) {
      throw new NotFoundException(err.message);
    }
  }
```

**user.schema.ts (where User type is defined)**

```
@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  userId: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  username: string;

  @Prop({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  password: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  accountType: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect TypeScript to be complaining about indexing into that object with strings. But in any case, if you use brackets notation, I don't think TypeScript broadens the type because you're using strings.

You can build the object with all of the properties from the start:

```typescript
async localRegister(createUserDto: LocalUserDto) {
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(createUserDto.password, 10);
    const createUserObj = {
        ...createUserDto,
        password: passwordHash,
        userId: uuid(),                // ***
        accountType: 'local',          // ***
    };

    this.userCreate(createUserObj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a property "dynamically", like this:

```
createUserObj['userId'] = uuid();
```

the typescript compiler cannot really determine the shape of the object. Try this, to let the compiler know exactly what properties are part of the new object:

```
let createUserObj = { 
    ...createUserDto, 
    password: passwordHash,
    userId: uuid(),
    accountType: 'local'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to cast the variable type after properties are added. Typescript won't allow you to change the type of the variable afterwards.

```
  async localRegister(createUserDto: LocalUserDto) {
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(createUserDto.password, 10);
    let createUserObj: Partial<User> = { ...createUserDto, password: passwordHash };

    createUserObj.userId = uuid();
    createUserObj.accountType = 'local';

    this.userCreate(createUserObj as User);
  }
```

Or give it sane defaults

```
  async localRegister(createUserDto: LocalUserDto) {
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(createUserDto.password, 10);
    let createUserObj: User = { 
      ...createUserDto,
      password: passwordHash,
      userId: 'invalid uuid',
      accounType: 'local'
    };

    createUserObj.userId = uuid();
    createUserObj.accountType = 'local';

    this.userCreate(createUserObj);
  }
```

Comment: <Pedantry>They aren't casts, they're type assertions.</Pedantry> :-) There's no need for type assertions or fake values in the OP's code.